# Finding the number of upper and lower case letter in a string in python

Tags: python, string, function, uppercase, lowercase

when I run the code it always shows 0 as results....
CODE:

```
def case_counter(string):
    lower=0
    upper=0
    for char in string:  
        if (string.islower()):
            lower=lower+1
        
        elif (string.isupper()):
            upper=upper+1
        
    print('the no of lower case:',lower)
    print('the no of upper case',upper)
string='ASDDFasfds'        
case_counter(string)
```

RESULT:
the no of lower case: 0
the no of upper case 0
EXPECTED:
the no of lower case:5
the no of upper case 5

Comment: you are testing against string, but want to test against char

Comment: so what do i do??

Comment: you change string to char in the if sentences.

Comment: got it ..... used char.islower() and char.isupper() as per the suggestions... the result is what I expected..... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When comparing lower and higher value for your purpose you have to use "char" variable Like the example in this code

```
def case_counter(string):
    lower=0
    upper=0
    for char in string:  
        if (char.islower()):
            lower=lower+1
        
        elif (char.isupper()):
            upper=upper+1
        
    print('the no of lower case:',lower)
    print('the no of upper case',upper)
string='ASDDFasfds'        
case_counter(string)
```

Comment: just did and got the expected output.... thanks .... but then when should I use string.islower() or string.isuuper() ???

Comment: I am glad that helped you. In your example "string" variable will be having the whole string i.e. ASDDFasfds So if you want to check the whole string is lower case or upper case you use the string variable. Look at the conditional for loop in python to learn more

Comment: is it possible to solve it using string.count()   method???/

Comment: string.count() will be useful if you want to count the repitition of substring. For example:string="ABABcdef" then use string.count("AB",0,len(string)) . This will return 2. For more information:```https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_count.htm```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `char.islower()` instead of `string.islower()` and you can do `lower+=1` instead of `lower=lower+1` and same for `upper`

Answer (score 0):

Your conditionals are incorrect. Update `string.islower()` and `string.isupper()` to `char.islower()` and `char.isupper()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to iritate over each character indiviudaly.
Now your program checks if whole string is written in uppercase or lowercase.

This means your code should look something like this:

```
def upper_lower(text):
    upper = 0
    lower = 0
    for i in text:
        if i.isupper():
            upper += 1
        else:
            lower +=1
    print('the no of lower case:',lower)
    print('the no of upper case',upper)
```